# Problems inserting data into MYSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am still a beginner at PHP/MYSQL and I am having difficulties inserting data into my MYSQL database. (I've originally tried using my localhost database but once i moved to an online server, everything seems to stop working.)

Right now, as soon as i submit the data from my index.php page.. it only refreshes the page and doesn't add any data.

However, when I go to submit.php, everything works fine and it adds an empty set of data to my results.php.

My codes are as follows. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>POST variables</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all">

</head>
<body>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anas12_test', 'a1b2c3d4', 'anas12_test');

if (!$con) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    echo '<div class="container">

            <form id="profiles">
            <div class="header">

            <h3>Hello there!</h3>
            <p>We want to know more about you! Share a few interesting details about yourself using the form below!</p>

            </div>

            <div class="sep"></div>

            <div class="inputs">

            <form action="submit.php" method="post">

            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" type="text">

            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" type="text">

            <input id="colour" name="colour" placeholder="Favourite Colour" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" type="text">

            <input id="music" name="music" placeholder="Favourite Song" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" type="text">

            <input id="superpower" name="superpower" placeholder="If you had a superhero ability, what would it be?" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" type="text">  

    <button id="submit" type="submit"name="submit" value="added">Submit!</button>


            </form> </div>

            </div>'; 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Submit.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anas12_test', 'a1b2c3d4', 'anas12_test');


if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
} else {
    $name = "";
}

if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
} else {
    $email = "";
}

if(isset($_POST["colour"])){
    $colour = $_POST["colour"];
} else {
    $colour = "";
}

if(isset($_POST["music"])){
    $music = $_POST["music"];
} else {
    $music = "";
}

if(isset($_POST["superpower"])){
    $superpower = $_POST["superpower"];
} else {
    $superpower = "";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO profiles (name, email, colour, music, superpower) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$colour', '$music', '$superpower')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
header ('location: results.php'.$query_string);
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
}

if($name !== "" && $email !== "" && $colour !== "" && $music !== "" && $superpower !== "") {

    $query_string = '?name=' . $name.'&email='.$email.'&colour='.$colour.'&music='.$music.'&superpower='.$superpower;
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header ('location: results.php'.$query_string);     

} 

?>
```

And my results page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>POST Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anas12_test', 'a1b2c3d4', 'anas12_test');


if(isset($_GET["name"])){
    $name = $_GET["name"];
} else {
    $name = "no name";
}

if(isset($_GET["email"])){
    $email = $_GET["email"];
} else {
    $email = "no email";
}

if(isset($_GET["colour"])){
    $colour = $_GET["colour"];
} else {
    $colour = "no colour:";
}

if(isset($_GET["music"])){
    $music = $_GET["music"];
} else {
    $music = "music";
}

if(isset($_GET["superpower"])){
    $superpower = $_GET["superpower"];
} else {
    $superpower = "superpower";
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profiles");

  echo "<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>";
    echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Favourite Colour</th>
    <th>Favourite Music</th>
    <th>Superhero Ability</th>
 </tr>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['colour'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['music'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['superpower'] . "</td>";

         echo "</tr>";}
    echo "</table>";
  echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: To expand on the SQL injection, use mysqli_real_escape_string to escape any untrusted (i.e. from the browser) text input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has no `action`, so it'll submit the form to the URL you loaded the page from, which will be `index.php`.

You need this:

```
        <form id="profiles" action="Submit.php" method="POST">
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the `method` portion as well - with no method, forms default to using GET

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise that i made that mistake! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful you have two form in your index.php.

```
<form id="profiles">
```

and

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
```

I think the first one is useless.